# Depicting inaccurate information about real organisations in fiction?

Tags: creative-writing

Could it be a problem (legal one) if in a fiction novel, I depict…

1. Law enforcement/military organisation with quite a few details about their organisational structure in an inaccurate manner.
2. Not naming any specific company or brand name, but rather depicting an entire industry in bad light (For eg: making claims that the insurance industry is in general prone to misrepresentation of facts while pitching their products) or more specifically stereotyping the industry behaviour.

Comment: So, have you ever read a novel which did either of these things. How often do they occur in published novels? Given this, what do you conclude in regard to your question?

Comment: @mbakeranalecta never came across a fiction novel where an entire industry was depicted in bad light (except industries already being in the bad light largely in media)... As for point 1 yes I have come across, but it is also possible that the author might have taken prior permission or something for that... its my first time writing fiction, so just covering all bases :)

Comment: This might be more of a question for https://law.stackexchange.com

Comment: Depends how important it is to your fiction novel

Answer (score 2):

I think, if you slander the insurance industry in general, that should not be a problem. But if you want to show one specific company being bad, you should use a fictitious company, or you might find a law suit taking the fun out of your next years.

The military and other government institutions (police, schools, parliament, etc.) are free to bash, and this is done every day in every tv show, movie, book, and so on. The simple reason for this is that it is impossible to use a fictional military for an existing country. There is only one. So it is understood that whatever you write about government institutions is fiction, unless you clearly state otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a problem from legal point of view? That's a question for [law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/). You might be able to protect yourself with a standard [All persons fictitious disclaimer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_persons_fictitious_disclaimer) in the preface:

> The story, all names, characters, and incidents portrayed in this novel are fictitious. No identification with actual persons, places, buildings, and products is intended or should be inferred.

but you should ask a lawyer for details.

But no matter what's legal, keep in mind what this means for your work. When you portray a real-world organization or industry in a way which is simply untrue, then that's a sign that you didn't do proper research before you wrote.

In the best case, the reader will know more about the subject than you do, realize you are just making stuff up, will feel disappointed by your general lack of effort, greatly lower their suspension of disbelief and see your whole work more sceptical.

In the worst case, the reader will believe your depictions, think they actually represent the reality and get a completely false impression of the subject you write about. This is deliberately misinforming your audience, which is simply irresponsible.

Think about how much you know about, say, police procedure. Likely most of what you believe to know about the daily work of police officers actually comes from fictional media. What if all that media depicted police work completely wrong? Would you realize that? What if it gave you a completely different impression of the thousands of people who work in the police force? What if you treat them completely differently than they actually deserve because of their wrong fictional representation?

So please be responsible and think about the many real people you indirectly write about when you depict a non-fictional organization.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I already asked this question on law.stackexchange but never got a satisfactory answer... as for inaccuracies, I was talking about all trivial things like designation and reporting structure, which is kind of difficult to research about, especially when it is about lesser known organizations from lesser known country (especially a country where my target audience is not located)... obviously I wish to be as accurate as possible, but with limited sources of information there's always a risk I'd miss something.